# VSCode regex find and select data from specific group (not replace)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Consider the following dataset:

```
<uses-configuration
android:reqFiveWayNav=["true" | "false"]
android:reqHardKeyboard=["true" | "false"]
android:reqKeyboardType=["undefined" | "nokeys" | "qwerty" | "twelvekey"]
android:reqNavigation=["undefined" | "nonav" | "dpad" | "trackball" | "wheel"]
android:reqTouchScreen=["undefined" | "notouch" | "stylus" | "finger"] />
```

I am trying to select all the values after `android:`
In order to do this, i am using `(a\w+:)(\w+)` which does exactly what i want. I know that I can use the search and replace and use`$2` to select the second group, but I dont want to replace anythin. I want to select anything the second group matches with `alt+enter` key press.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is a lookaround.  I don't believe that vscode supports lookbehinds (see [issues: lookbehind support coming](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9140)).  But it does support lookaheads so :

```
(\w+)(?=\=\[.*\])
```

should work for you as long as your desired values are followed by "`[.*]`" and nothing undesired has that pattern. The lookahead part will not be selected by vscode.  And then <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> selects all the matches.

If lookbehind was supported, maybe soon, this would work:

```
\b(?<=a\w+:)(\w+)\b
```

---

Just a note that indeed **lookbehinds** were implemented in vscode since the question and answer so the lookbehind solution `\b(?<=a\w+:)(\w+)\b` does work now.